# finite dimensional vector spaces with a symmetric bilinear form have an orthogonal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

[image]

I am confused about case 2, where $\exists v \in V$ such that $f(v,v) \not= 0$.

I have some questions:

1) where in the proof have we used the fact that $f(v,v) \not= 0$ - I don't see how this was used at all

2) why is $\text{span} \{v \} $ have dimension 1?

many thanks to anyone who can help me clear this up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(v,v)\ne0$ then certainly $v\ne0$ and then $\{v\}^\perp$ is $n-1$ dimensional subspace. $\operatorname{span}(v)$ is generated by **one** non-zero vector so it's $1$-dimensional subspace.